# How to configure multiple domain on single hosting

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, shared-hosting, serveralias

I would multiple domain on single hosting. My project files inside this hosting plan. I run same server.

How to multiple hosting (vhost) acccess to my project files?

For example: my project files in:

```
/var/www/virtual/myproject.com/htdocs
```

and clients...

```
/var/www/virtual/myclient1.com/htdocs
/var/www/virtual/myclient2.com/htdocs
/var/www/virtual/myclientN.com/htdocs
```

When access to www.myclient1.com run project file.

Please help me.

Comment: @DrewKhoury I tried ServerAlias and VirtualDirectory methods. Client hostings have mail accounts. Well I add a hosting plan for every client. But directory linked to myproject.com.

Comment: you should post your configuration and the errors that you're getting so we can help.

Answer (score -2):

In case you were using Apache, you should start reading the vhost documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/.